# PHP changes X and Y axis of mysql database results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a little help with the best way to get results to display the way I want from as few as possible database queries.

I would like to use one of my queries results columns as new unique columns for another table and merge like data.

For example

I run this query..

```
SELECT pd.production_date,pd.production_time,pd.production_net,
      p.part_number, w.worker_name
      FROM production as pd
      INNER JOIN parts as p
      ON pd.product_id = p.part_id
      INNER JOIN locations as l
      ON pd.location_id = l.location_id
      INNER JOIN workers as w
      ON pd.worker_id = w.worker_id
      WHERE pd.production_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
      AND p.part_number='$part_number'
      ORDER BY pd.production_date
```

And I will get results like this:

```
production_date--production_time--production_net--worker_name
2013-01-10--390--96--MMahe
2013-01-10--400--101--RMaloney
2013-01-11--460--96--JBurris
2013-01-11--210--43--MMahe
2013-01-14--285--48--LTaylor
2013-01-16--60--8--MRocquemore
2013-01-16--460--90--TUsher
2013-01-17--450--85--MRocquemore
2013-01-17--460--84--TUsher
2013-01-18--450--73--MRocquemore
2013-01-18--460--93--TUsher
2013-01-18--240--24--JBurris
```

I then would like to display these results on a webpage like this:

```
Operators|01-10-2013|01-11-2013|01-14-2013|01-16-2013|01-17-2013|01-18-2013

MMahe|96|43|x|x|x|x

RMaloney|101|x|x|x|x|x

JBurris|x|96|x|x|x|24

LTaylor|x|x|48|x|x|x

MRocquemore|x|x|x|8|85|73

TUsher|x|x|x|90|84|93
```

My thought was first I need to filter my days to unique values then spit them out as the columns, which I have accomplished with this

```
  $query=mysql_query($sql);
  $days = array();
  $results.='<div><table border="0"><th>Operator</th>';
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      array_push($days,$row['production_date']);
  }
      $days=array_unique($days);
      $column_count=count($days);
      $n=0;
      //create the columns (days) by looping through unique days
      foreach($days as $value) {
          $results.='<th>'.$value.'</th>';
      }//end foreach
```

But now I don't see a way forward of listing values in the appropriate cells. 
Do you have experience with doing this sort of data manipulation or can point me to a good example?

Comment: You want to mirror a matrix. This has been asked and answered before as long as you're concerned for something you've got in arrays (as you do as I see). Please use the search before asking a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - how to flip the rows and columns of a 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221476/php-how-to-flip-the-rows-and-columns-of-a-2d-array)

Comment: Appreciate the response but that didn't really help me. I'm unable to get any results here for help because I'm not quite what to search for. All my attempts lead to math related questions. If you happen to have an example to point me to I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Divide your problem. Solve each part. Then combine the solutions. You should be finished after the next three hours have passed. - *Hint:* Ask the question with your array only, we're not interested where that array comes from ;) - This will greatly remove the code and the description in your question allowing others users to more focus on *your concrete problem*.

Comment: What are operators? The first row in output you want to see.