# How to separated key values with same index in a new multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have below multidimensional array and need help to convert multidimensional in the specific formation

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 50
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 48
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 0
        )

)
```

and want to convert like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 48
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 50
            [3] => 0
        )
)
```

On the above output, I have separated key values with the same index in a new array.

Is it possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I think what you're asking has been asked before. You might want to check out  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221476/php-how-to-flip-the-rows-and-columns-of-a-2d-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution from the [PHP - how to flip the rows and columns of a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15130980/10780177) post

```
$out = array();
foreach ($array as  $rowkey => $row) {
    foreach($row as $colkey => $col){
        $out[$colkey][$rowkey]=$col;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.array-map.php) function

```
$result = array_map(null, ...$array);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7882c478476daa604a66c3b20a5835051812ed74)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solutions:

```
<?php

$array =
[
    0 =>
        [
            0 => 20,
            1 => 15,
            2 => 0
        ],

    1 =>
        [
            0 => 28,
            1 => 45,
            2 => 0
        ],

    2 =>
        [
            0 => 20,
            1 => 5,
            2 => 50
        ],

    3 =>
        [
            0 => 48,
            1 => 20,
            2 => 0
        ]
];

$result = [];
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($value); $i++) {
        $result[$i][] = $value[$i];
    }
}


var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    int(20)
    [1]=>
    int(28)
    [2]=>
    int(20)
    [3]=>
    int(48)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    int(15)
    [1]=>
    int(45)
    [2]=>
    int(5)
    [3]=>
    int(20)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    int(50)
    [3]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine and doing what you are looking for, try to copy paste on the editor and run it.

```
<?php 
   $originalArray = Array(
         Array
            (
                 20,
                 15,
                 0
            ),

         Array
            (
                 28,
                 45,
                 0
            ),

         Array
            (
                 20,
                 5,
                 50
            ),

         Array
            (
                 48,
                 20,
                 0
            )

    ); //echo"<pre>";print_R($originalArray); 00 10 20 30 40 : 01,11,21,31 :  02,12,22,32,    
$newArray =array();
//echo count($originalArray);
//echo count($originalArray[1]);
$count = array_map('count', $originalArray);
$min = array_keys($count , max($count))[0];
$largest_arr = $originalArray[$min];

for($i=0;$i<count($largest_arr);$i++){
array_push($newArray,$originalArray[$i]);
    for($j=0;$j<count($originalArray);$j++){
echo $j."--".$i."---".count($originalArray)."----".$originalArray[$j][$i]."<br>";
        array_push($newArray[$i],$originalArray[$j][$i]);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_R($newArray);
?>
```